# Using C++ fmtlib, is there a cleaner way to append a sequence of data to a string than using std::ostringstream?

Tags: c++, string, format, append, fmt

The fmtlib package provides a clean, readable and fast way to format string data in C++, but I cannot find a clean and readable way to use it to append a sequence of data to a string.

After much googling, I've come up with a working solution, but it is much more verbose than using the typical approach of std streams and chevrons. I can't any/many examples of this using fmtlib, so I'm hoping some expert out there knows a neater way of doing this.

```
 // Here is an fmtlib version of dump_line.  I don't like it.  using 'cout' seems cleaner and simpler.
virtual void dump_line( const char* msg, uint8_t* dataline )
{
  fmt::memory_buffer out;
  format_to(out, "{} :", msg);
  for( int jj=0; jj<m_cacheStore.p_LineSize; jj++) {
    format_to(out, " [{}]={}", jj, (int)dataline[jj] );
  }
  fmt::print("{}\n",fmt::to_string(out) );
}

// Here is the typical approach using cout and chevrons.
// Nice and simple. 
virtual void dump_line( const char* msg, uint8_t* dataline )
{
  cout << msg << " : " ;
  for( int jj=0; jj<m_cacheStore.p_LineSize; jj++)
    cout << " [" << jj << "]=" << (int)dataline[jj];
  cout<<endl;
}
```

I'm just dumping an array of ints to stdout to look like this:
 [0]=2 [1]=0 [2]=0 [3]=0 [4]=1 [5]=0 [6]=0 [7]=0

Answer (score 1):

You can write to the output stream directly without an intermediate buffer:

```cpp
virtual void dump_line(const char* msg, uint8_t* dataline) {
  fmt::print("{} :", msg);
  for (int jj=0; jj<m_cacheStore.p_LineSize; jj++) {
    fmt::print(" [{}]={}", jj, dataline[jj]);
  }
  fmt::print("\n");
}
```

Note that you don't need to cast `dataline[jj]` to `int`, because unlike iostreams, {fmt} correctly handles `uint8_t`.

If you want to build a string you can either write to a `memory_buffer` or pass `back_insert_iterator` to `format_to`.